# How do I insert a photo at the top of the sidebar?

Tags: images, widgets, sidebar

http://www.beautybykatlin.com/

Hello,
How do I add an image at the top of the sidebar? I had one there but I deleted it and I don't know how to get it back. Please help!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, it seems that the broken image on the top left side is your logo. I suspect there might be a logo upload for the theme but we won't be able to direct you to where that logo upload form is because it can vary depending on the theme. You'll want to check for the theme options area often located under the Appearance menu in the admin dashboard.

Comment: OK-I actually just figured it out! Thank you!